# Switch Between Storyboards Using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I have a storyboard that is getting too large in my Xcode project and slowing down my computer. How do I programmatically (or manually using storyboarding) go from one of my views in the current storyboard using a button to advance to a view on the new storyboard?

Semi-new with Xcode so the simpler the better. Thanks!

Comment: How many view controllers do you have? It may be better to address the reason as to why you have so many view controllers.

Comment: I have about 20 view controllers simply because I have a lot of math going on in my code and don't want to complicate the views with more code.

Comment: Don't forget to set your ```unwind segues``` as well.  You can read more about that here: [Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

Comment: take a look at this http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.pt/2012/06/linking-storyboard.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do it programatically this way:

**Swift 3+**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as UIViewController
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Older**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as UIViewController
presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In Sort you can do it like:

```
presentViewController( UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And don't forget to give ID to your nextViewController.

For more Info refer [THIS](http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2012/11/instantiate-view-controller-using.html).

Answer (score 41):

## 0 Lines of Code

#### Using Interface Builder

1. Add a **Storyboard Reference** to the source storyboard
   [image: Storyboard Reference]
2. Control-Drag from the `UIButton` to that **Storyboard Reference**
   [image]
3. In the *Attributes inspector* of the **Storyboard Reference** placeholder, specify the destination **Storyboard** and optionally the destination **Reference ID** of the target `UIViewController` and **Bundle**.
   [image]

#### Complete picture

[image]

Comment: Awesome that you are giving the explanation using storyboard objects! Very useful

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where did you get to know about this? Amazing!

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 solution:

```
present( UIStoryboard(name: "CreateOrder", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstOrderViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```